# iOS UIImageView smooth Image presentation

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching, asynchronous, uiimageview

One of the ways to improve user experience in iOS while showing images is to download them asynchronously without blocking the main thread and showing them....

But I want to add something to this -

1. Initially when there is no image,show a spinner while the async download has started.
2. After the download cache the image on local iOS disk for later use.
3. After the download populate the `image` part of `UIImageView`.
4. And dont just plonk the image into view for user. Showly Fade in the user (i.e. from alpha 0.0 to 1.0)

I have been using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for sometime now. It works well but does not satisfy my 1st requirement (about spinner) and 4th.

Is there any help out there to satisfy all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three20 http://www.three20.info has a TTImageView class that statisfies 2-3, you can subclass it and overwrite `setImage:` and create the fade animation there. (or just modify TTImageView.m directly).
Spinner is easy as well when you modify TTImageView you can add a TTActivityView on top and remove it on `setImage:`

Comment: dont you think Tree20 is a huge library to add just for this?

Comment: yeah Three20 is huge.. maybe you can limit the number of libs you include? Three20Core, Three20UI and Three20Network should be sufficient. If this is too much i'd suggest reimplementing the minimum needed code (request caching, imageview request management) and selling it for a lot of $$ :)

Comment: another downside is that Three20 has some very old code (iOS 2.0 SDK) inside its request/response delegate and caching logic (which is because NSURLConnection delegates are called on the main thread) and may block your main thread if you have LOTs of requests and ttimageviews (20-50, more that just for uitableview use).